# How could I specify output file name based on input file name?

Tags: gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

How could I specify output file name based on input file name?

I'm specifically trying to use grunt task (`grunt-closure-tools` or `grunt-closure-compiler`) to compile (minify) multiple javascript files, let's say all satisfying `'/source/**/*.js'` and want to output them in format `$(original_file_path_without_extension).min.js`

In all samples I've seen, the output is specified as single file only but I need to minify each file separately and into the same folder where the original file comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out the configuration. The trick is in building the files object dynamically (as described [here](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)). My configuration for `grunt-closure-tools` looks like this:

```
closureCompiler: {
    options: {
        // .. YOUR OPTIONS (ommited)
    },
    minify: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ['source/**/*.js', '!source/**/*.min.js'],
                ext: '.min.js'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closure-compiler is designed to simultaneously compile all of your javascript into a single file to minimize requests. There are really only two use cases where separate output files are supported:

## Multiple modules

In order to preserve renaming references, you'll have to compile your files simultaneously. The way to do that and maintain separate files is with modules. See [How do I split my javascript into modules using Google's Closure Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395810/how-do-i-split-my-javascript-into-modules-using-googles-closure-compiler/10401030#10401030)

## Non-related Files

If your files don't have inter-dependencies, then you would simply run your grunt task multiple times - one for each file.

Comment: The files are somewhat related, they contain angular modules for single page application. They are loaded only if required (depending on user's workflow). Thanks anyway for GCC comments.