# How to minify js from two independent services to work together on the frontend

Tags: javascript, package, web-deployment, google-closure-compiler, modularity

I have a 'modular' backend where two different services/repos are serving up client side js to the same client. I need the JS from both sources to be minified and work together as one is dependent on the other. They are currently minified independently so the js breaks.
edit: To clarify the minification is aggressive and is minifying all names.

Comment: Minified js should not break the code in any way, since it preserves accessible variable names. Please show the error message and relevant code.

Comment: As long as you don't use the advanced setup, you really shouldn't have errors

Comment: @Bálint advanced setup is being used.

Comment: Why? Just put it to simple

Comment: @Bálint it has to be inlined and super small it is for GA stuff

Comment: Can you concatenate the 2 files?

Comment: @Bálint no they are from different services / teams. :)

Comment: Then you need to use the simple setup.

Comment: How often does code from one script need to call into the other script? If it isn't too often, with Closure Compiler, you can add `@export` on the functions that are in one script but called from the other, and enable the `--generate_exports` flag. There are other approaches that might work but this is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile them together. You can use the [code splitting flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395810/how-do-i-split-my-javascript-into-modules-using-googles-closure-compiler/10401030#10401030) to direct distinct inputs into unique output files. You will get maximum renaming with this method.

If you absolutely cannot compile them at the same time, you'll have to eliminate most of the benefits of ADVANCED mode and create externs and exports so that the scripts can coordinate. In this way they are both external to each other.

Comment: This is the conclusion I came to. Examples listed down the page here: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3