# Google Closure Project Dependency

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I have two projects, project A and B, both built with the Google Closure Library.

How can I make project B dependent on Project A so that I can `goog.require` Project A modules in Project B allowing for seamless integration(compilation, minification etc)?

Comment: look at modules. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204474/using-the-module-option-in-closure-compiler-to-create-multiple-output-files

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is - can you not just use the same goog.provide/goog.require statements between your projects and compile both together at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both projects can be compiled then you can compile any project into any project. Dependency should be solved with goog.require and goog.provide

When I was looking into how to use lime I wrote a wiki after fiddling with where to put the code and how to use calcdeps.py you can find it here: [WIKI: How to use Lime (how to use closure-compiler with 3rd party (closure) libraries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432800/wiki-how-to-use-lime-how-to-use-closure-compiler-with-3rd-party-closure-libr)

Basically Lime is a 3rd party library but any code that provide something and is used by other code can be compiled with that other code.